# Difference between the `className` prop and the new MUI system utility `sx` prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Ive mostly been using the `makeStyles` hook to style my material-ui components. It's fairly straightforward and modular and performant.

Material-UI v5 has the [new](https://next.material-ui.com/system/basics/#the-sx-prop) `sx` prop that seems fairly promising, but towards the bottom of their docs there, they mention that there is a performance tradeoff.

My question is what's the ultimate difference here between `makeStyles` and `sx`, and should I consider switching?

I feel like I should also point out that using the `sx` prop seems to bulk up the `return` section of the code and using `makeStyles` just feels cleaner.

Am I missing something here or is there something revolutionary about `sx`, that should make me want to use it?

Comment: `sx` looks like it's more comparable to the `style` prop so I think the question should be "what's the difference between the new `sx` prop and the `style` prop"

Comment: I don't think so. According to the docs, it's optimized meaning it's like `style` only in a syntactical sense

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding SX is the alternative of style.

When it comes to ReactJs, if you try to use inline styles you need to

In HTML:

```
<div class="awesome" style="background-color: #f00">
  <p style="font-size:14px;">
</div>
```

Converted to JSX:

```
<div className="awesome" style={{backgroundColor: '#f00'}}>
   <p style={{fontSize: '14px'}}></p>
</div>
```

With SX : It is a super-set, Responsive, themes

```
<div sx={{ width: { tablet: 100, laptop: 300, desktop: 500, }, }} > 
    This box has a responsive width 
</div>
```

Don't be in a Hurry to use, as per the benchmark results it is taking lot of time https://next.material-ui.com/system/basics/#performance-tradeoff